# Python and Pandas - Numbering a column based after sorting and based on date other than using loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

am new to Stack overflow so apologies if my question is unclear/formatting is wrong. (using excel screenshot for illustration but the question is for python/pandas)

Currently I have a dataframe in python like this below. I am trying to find out which is the 1st/2nd contract month etc for each particular "Date" and number them accordingly. The number has to restart as the date changes. This dataframe has is quite large with a million rows of data at least.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir8hc.png)

Currently I am using loop in python to do this. Basically snippet of code below. Count starts from 0 and the function is used to isolate how each "Date" to sort the "Contract Month" and then number it. After which I append it to a dataframe and continue on in a loop.

Unfortunately, this is way slower than I thought. Suspect it is due to the way I wrote the loop mechanism...just wondering if there is a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
    while count < period:

        def previous_day(refday):                             
            refdayindex=DS2_df_date.index(refday)
            return DS2_df_date[refdayindex-count]

        selectedday = (previous_day(Enddate))

        DS2_Sortcontracts=DS2_df.loc[DS2_df['Date'] == selectedday]
        DS2_Sortcontracts = DS2_Sortcontracts.sort_values(by='Contract')
        DS2_Sortcontracts = DS2_Sortcontracts.reset_index(drop=True)
        DS2_Sortcontracts.index = DS2_Sortcontracts.index + 1
        DS2_Sortcontracts['Chain']=DS2_Sortcontracts.index
        DS2_df2=DS2_df2.append(DS2_Sortcontracts)
        count=count+1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I would first convert the 'Date' and 'Contract Month' fields to datetime so they can be sorted properly, then use use `cumcount` with `assign` and `groupby` .

```
#Convert to date time for sorting
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Contract Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract Month'],format='%d%b%Y')

#Sort by date and contract month
df.sort_values(by=['Date','Contract Month'])

#Count contract months within each 'Date group
df = df.assign(numbering=df.groupby('Date')['Contract Month'].cumcount()+1)
```

In:

```
              Date Contract Month
    0   13/10/2017      01Jan2020
    1   13/10/2017      01Feb2020
    2   13/10/2017      01Mar2020
    3   13/10/2017      01Apr2020
    4   13/10/2017      01May2020
    5   13/10/2017      01Jun2020
    6   12/10/2017      01Jan2020
    7   12/10/2017      01Feb2020
    8   12/10/2017      01Mar2020
    9   12/10/2017      01Apr2020
    10  12/10/2017      01May2020
    11  12/10/2017      01Jun2020
    12  11/10/2017      01Jan2020
    13  11/10/2017      01Feb2020
    14  11/10/2017      01Mar2020
    15  11/10/2017      01Apr2020
    16  11/10/2017      01May2020
    17  11/10/2017      01Jun2020
    18  11/10/2017      01Jul2020
```

Out:

```
         Date Contract Month  numbering
12 2017-10-11     2020-01-01          1
13 2017-10-11     2020-02-01          2
14 2017-10-11     2020-03-01          3
15 2017-10-11     2020-04-01          4
16 2017-10-11     2020-05-01          5
17 2017-10-11     2020-06-01          6
18 2017-10-11     2020-07-01          7
6  2017-10-12     2020-01-01          1
7  2017-10-12     2020-02-01          2
8  2017-10-12     2020-03-01          3
9  2017-10-12     2020-04-01          4
10 2017-10-12     2020-05-01          5
11 2017-10-12     2020-06-01          6
0  2017-10-13     2020-01-01          1
1  2017-10-13     2020-02-01          2
2  2017-10-13     2020-03-01          3
3  2017-10-13     2020-04-01          4
4  2017-10-13     2020-05-01          5
5  2017-10-13     2020-06-01          6
```